# How to create a macro that gets the value of an enum type?

Tags: enums, macros, rust

My enum looks like this:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Type {
    GLnull,
    GLenum(GLenum),
    GLboolean(GLboolean),
    GLint(GLint),
    GLbyte(GLbyte),
    GLshort(GLshort),
    GLclampx(GLclampx),
    GLubyte(GLubyte),
    GLushort(GLushort),
    GLuint(GLuint),
    GLsizei(GLsizei),
    GLclampf(GLclampf),
    GLdouble(GLdouble),
    GLclampd(GLclampd),
    GLfloat_4fv((GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)),
    GLfloat(GLfloat),
    GLintptr(GLintptr),
    GLsizeiptr(GLsizeiptr),
    GLbitfield(GLbitfield),
    GLchar_ptr(String),
}

macro_rules! get{
    ($e:expr) => {
        match $e {
            Type::GLsizei(x) => { x }
            Type::GLbitfield(x) => { x }
            _ => { 0 }
        }
    }
}
```

Now how do I create a macro that gets the value of the enum type?

Comment: How would you expect this to work? You cannot write a match that has incompatible types depending on the pattern that is matched. That just doesn't type check. An alternative would be to use a macro that tries to extract the value of a given variant, but then you might as well go for a function (or just use `if let`).

Answer (score -1):

Like @aochagavia say there is no point to have a macro if you must do specific stuff with your enum.

The following macro could help you, the purpose is to have a macro that create a enum and generate some method. This only work if all variant have one type.

```rust
macro_rules! foo {
    ($($(#[$meta:meta])* foo $name:ident($ty:ty),)*) => {
        #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
        pub enum Foo {
            $($(#[$meta])* $name($ty),)*
        }
        impl Foo {
            pub fn display(&self) {
                match *self {
                    $(Foo::$name(x) => println!("{}", x),)*
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

foo! {
    foo A(i32),
    foo B(i64),
}

fn main() {
    let a = Foo::A(32);
    let b = Foo::B(64);

    a.display();
    b.display();
}
```

The [original](https://github.com/KokaKiwi/amf/blob/54254b76156c771fb9bfbe690bff19408d447178/src/markers.rs#L1) macro is from @koka-el-kiwi, I take it as an example and modification for your case.

Comment: @Shepmaster Just a question that is you who downvote me? If that is you can you tell me why? This doesn't answer the question? "How to create a macro that gets the value of an enum type?"

Answer (score -2):

The following method is also available

```
pub enum Type<T> {
    gli32(T),
    gli64(T),
    glfloat4fv(T),
    glString(T),
    glVec(T),
}

impl<T> Type<T> {
    pub fn unwarp(&self) -> &T {
        match *self {
            Type::gli32(ref x) => x,
            Type::gli64(ref x) => x,
            Type::glfloat4fv(ref x) => x,
            Type::glString(ref x) => x,
            Type::glVec(ref x) => x,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let f = Type::gli32(32 as i32);
    let ff64 = Type::gli64((64, 32));
    let f4fv = Type::glfloat4fv((0.1, 0.2, 0.0));
    let cstr = Type::glString(CString::new("glstring").unwrap());
    let ve = [1, 2, 3, 5];
    let glve = Type::glVec(ve);

    println!("f ={} {:?} {:?} {:?}",
             f.unwarp(),
             f4fv.unwarp(),
             cstr.unwarp(),
             glve.unwarp());
}
```

Comment: Giant blocks of code should be accompanied by prose to describe **what** changes were made and **why** they solve the problem.

Comment: Also, it's spelled `unwrap`.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected, it's create 5 enum. Not one.